# Adding tags for SEO in clothing website

Tags: seo, google, web-development, search-engines, tags

I am building a site for a women's accessories brand.

The site has a Homepage, a Store page (where all accessories are displayed), a page for each of the accessories description, an about page and a contact page. There is also a whole set up for shopping cart and checkout (irrelevant to this question).

My issue is the SEO. Where can I put the keywords? The home page has only the menu and some photos. The store page displays the items and its titles. Then the specific item's page has a description of the item (pulled from the database), category and price. However, I feel like this is not enough for SEO for google ranking.

Where could I add tags in this type of site?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to insert keywords in your pages:. I assume *women accessories* are your keywords.

- in the `<title>` tag (example for the home page: *Women's accessories - Brand*)
- in the `<h1>` tag (example for the home page: *Brand women's accessories*)
- in the `<h2>` tags if you can
- in the `<p>` tags

For pages without a real content, you need to add some; it's important for SEO. During writing of this content, think of applying variations on displayed keywords to avoid being penalized for keyword stuffing.

Comment: Thx! So, for my page displaying items, I should add a h1, h2 tag? For example, have a title for the page? Since currently I just display items

Comment: For a good SEO, you need to use semantic markup like `<title>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>` tags.